# replace the href value with label text in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

what i am trying to do is sharing a label text value as url link on twitter but its not working as expected. whats wrong with my code ..

my label value is generated from db:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblReferralURL" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Blue" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>

<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://google.com" id="TwitterLink" class="twitter" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin','left=300,top=100,width=650,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;">Tweet New</a>

 $(document).ready(function () {
            var para = $('#cphPage_lblReferralURL').html();
            $('#TwitterLink').attr('href', function () {               

                return this.href + '?url=' + para;
            });          
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Id is wrong change this line into:

```
var para = $('#lblReferralURL').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change http://www.example.com/ with your url and New Text with your text.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#TwitterLink").attr("href", "http://www.example.com/");
   $("#TwitterLink").html("New Text");   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://google.com" id="TwitterLink" class="twitter" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin','left=300,top=100,width=650,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;">Tweet New</a>
```